# In magit, is there a way to use user defined functions on global-map?

Tags: key-bindings, magit

I updated magit today using el-get.

When I defined a function,

```
(global-set-key "c" 
  (lambda () (interactive) (call-interactively 'self-insert-command)))
```

I couldn't use `c c` magit status buffer to commit. I get the following *message* buffer:

```
funcall-interactively: Buffer is read-only: #<buffer *magit-commit-popup*>
enter code here
```

Is there a proper way for user defined functions in magit?

Note that defining minor-mode doesn't solve my problem as I want to bind functions in global map.

Answer (score 2):

When you press <kbd>c c</kbd> to create a commit from inside a Magit buffer, this is what happens:

The first <kbd>c</kbd> constitutes a complete key binding, established in `magit-mode-map`. The bound command is `magit-commit-popup`, which shows the commit popup in a new buffer.

The second <kbd>c</kbd> also is a complete key binding. It is invoked while the popup buffer is already the current buffer, and it is established in `magit-popup-mode-map` like so:

```
(define-key magit-popup-mode-map [remap self-insert-command]
  'magit-invoke-popup-action)
```

I.e. whenever a key would be bound to `self-insert-command` without this binding, then bind it to `magit-invoke-popup-action` instead. See [Remapping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html) for more information.

Because you have mutilated <kbd>c</kbd>'s binding in `global-mode`, that doesn't work anymore. Binding <kbd>c</kbd> to that lambda has absolutely no benefit. It does the same thing as using `self-insert-command` directly would. And that's even the default binding, so binding to that lambda does not even change the behavior in normal circumstances.

But using a lambda causes the binding to lose its "identity", which results in Magit, and all other packages that do remap `self-insert-command` (e.g. `isearch`) to something else, to break.

You should *never* override a `self-insert-command` binding in `global-map`, certainly not for alphanumeric keys.

> Note that defining minor-mode doesn't solve my problem

Depending on what you actually want to do (please explain what it is), this might be your only option. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not Emacs expert like you, so please let me know if there is solution. I'm using over 50+ emacs lisp packages and worrying if random packages activate their minor-mode, how can we ensure user defined keybinds in minor mode? I always want to prior other minor-mode map keybinds than my keybinds. As the example, I use an emacs e-mail client `mew` and it binds almost "a" to "z" keys on minor-mode-map. I want to use key pair "C-u w" to spell check at point of cursor, but without C-u, I want to ignore the spell check. I do same thing in `twittering-mode`.

Comment: As the potential reason, I like Emacs default keybinds and I don't want to change from default. In that case, there aren't many empty key combinations except C-u + a-z in short keystroke. (I wouldn't use C-M-s- keys or something similar due to my short fingers)

Comment: The [`bind-key`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) package provides a mechanism for doing this. You don't actually have to use that package if you don't want to, the essential part is just [this](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/d867b0370e4e311c71665ccaa418374a15097461/bind-key.el#L118-L130).